How do data acquisition systems work?
This is a theoretical question.
All the signal processing electronic systems I have developed up to now have customized electronics to filter out unwanted noise.
Because their electronic filters are customized, they serve a particular task and are not universal in application.
There are data acquisition systems (DAS) like the PowerLab range of equipment (This page has some technical details) which claim they can handle different types of signals, like electro cardiogram, pulse, blood pressure, etc. through a single input channel.
How can these instruments do this?

Did you find any datasheet for this thing? The web page has a lot of marketing but no proper technical specifications.

Data acquisition hardware is usually more general than what you're assuming, there's one or more ADCs running at some max frequency and accepting some voltage, possibly with some digital IO. The user then connects some signal that is compatible with those specs. If you're asking about blood pressure monitoring, probably they also sell a blood pressure monitor that plugs into the data acquisition system.

@asdfex I found a page with some technical details and have updated my question with the link.

@user1850479 they do have different front ends for different instruments, like a BP apparatus, a spirometer etc etc which can be connected to this PowerLab DAS. But if they have separate electronics for separate instruments, what is the role of this Data Acquisition System? Why does this need analog-digital convertors?

Is it possible that the data acquisition system has no filters but just ADCs and microcontrollers to organize and format the filtered data and send it to the computer, and the front end electronics has the main dedicated filters??

And if its just Analog-Digital convertors and microcontrollers, why is it so big?

The role of the data acquisition system is to take the analog signal from some other device and record it in computer memory. Think of it as the interface between the analog hardware that creates a signal (transducers, photodiode, opamps, etc) and the software that interprets that signal and displays something on the screen (e.g. a calibrated blood pressure measurement). You need the ADC because otherwise the computer would not be able to access the analog data. There may also be digital or analog outputs that control things (e.g. turn on a light or actuate a motor).

They say they can do it, but they don't say they do it well :)
